# Universal Image Loader - load from cache if available else load from web causing havoc in grid list

Tags: caching, gridview, universal-image-loader

I have a grid list and i use UIL to load images from server. What i need is , if the file already exists in the cache i want to load that from cache otherwise i want to make a web request.

UIL's cache policy only works for a session. Soon after i close the app and start again after some time, it again loads from the web. Even though files are already in cache.

Even if i try my own logic, the whole thing gets messed up. Scrolling up and down causes images to disappear sometimes.

Here is the list row of my adapter - grid pair:

```
    File imageFile = _imageLoader.getDiscCache().get(url);

thumbHolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

if (imageFile.exists()) 
{
    String decoded = Uri.decode(Uri.fromFile(imageFile).toString());
    _imageLoader.displayImage(decoded, thumbHolder, _options);
}
else
{
    _imageLoader.displayImage(url, thumbHolder, _options);
}
```

My UIL init is like this:

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(this, "composetest");

    if(!cacheDir.exists())
    cacheDir.mkdirs();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
    .threadPoolSize(3)
    .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
    .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
    .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
    .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
    .discCache(new TotalSizeLimitedDiscCache(cacheDir, (30 * 1024 * 1024)))
    .discCacheSize(30 * 1024 * 1024)
    .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
    .build();

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisc(true)
    .build();

    localoptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .build();

    imageLoader.init(config);
```

UIL docs says it picks from cache if file is already loaded. But each time i start the app it loads from web. how can i make it always read cached file if already loaded else request file from web. ??

Comment: why do you know it is loading from web? have you made any tests or it is just  that you figure it out?

Comment: Its taking the same time to load the files at it does from internet. When it loads from disc cache i can see the speed difference.